# Using subversion with spacemacs

Tags: emacs

Is there anybody use subversion in spacemacs ? 
Or any suggestion for emacs newbie about using svn in emacs ? 
I just want to use log, diff, blame in editor.

Comment: Not sure if Spacemacs redefines all the key bindings, but in plain Emacs, log is `C-x v l`, diff is `C-x v =`, blame is `C-x v g`, and for an overview of your working copy use `C-x v d`.

Comment: http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Version-Control.html

Answer (score 2):

In the default configuration, Spacemacs has an SVN entry in the mode line. You can click it for the common operations. It will also show the keyboard shortcuts for those, as well. As suggested by @legoscia in the comment, the shortcuts start with C-x. Blame is called Annotate in the menu.

[image]